# Error in Evaluate statement macro

Tags: lotusscript, lotus-designer

I have a problem with an `evaluate statement`. I am trying to use this function into in a class, because I want to use the formula `@DbLookup` into lotusscript.

**This is my class code**:

```
Class DirectorSucursal

    Private m_branch As String

    'Constructor class
    Public Sub New (branch)
        me.m_branch = branch
    End Sub

    'Deleter Class
    Public Sub Delete

    End Sub

    'Function show the field value
    Public sub GetBranch
        MsgBox m_branch
    End Sub

    'Function get the name director
    Public Function getNameDirector

        getNameDirector = Evaluate ({@DbLookup("":"NoCache";"C1256EAD:00478951";"People2"; "D" + m_branch; "FullName"})

    End Function

End Class
```

I have an error in the line of `getNameDirector = ...`

> Error in evaluate macro

**What am i doing wrong?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
getNameDirector = Evaluate({@DbLookup("":"NoCache";"C1256EAD:00478951";"People2"; "D} + m_branch + {"; "FullName")})
```

You have to put variable m_branch outside the {...} strings and you missed @DbLookup's closing ")".

Comment: Also, I believe he needs a colon instead of a semicolon between "C1256EAD:00478951" and "People2".

Comment: @Richard: No, "C1256EAD:00478951" is the database and "People2" is the view name. Both are separate parameters. (colon would be between server and database).

Comment: I stand corrected. I must have coded 10,000 DbLookups in the last 25 years, but something in my mind said db:view was a list. Wrong! I must be getting old :-)