# Evaluate statement (@DbLookUp) doesn't work with Lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-designer

The last week I asked how to solve an error in an `evaluate statement` ([Error in Evaluate statement macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719504/error-in-evaluate-statement-macro)).

Once fix it, I have other error with the same evaluate statement, it doesn't give me any value.

I will describe what I have and what I try.

**@DbLookup in Calculate Text**

I have this code into in an calculate Text and it works fine.

```
suc := @Trim(@Left(LlcPoliza;2));
_lkp := _lkp := @DbLookup("":"NoCache";"C1256EAD:00478951";"People2"; "D"+suc; "FullName");
@If( @IsError( _lkp ) ; " " ; _lkp );
@Name([CN];_lkp)
```

> `LlcPoliza` is a document field (`doc.LlcPoliza`) and in a document it has for example the value **C2H2H2**.
>
> The formula give first the value **C2** and then look up into `People2` who is **D+C2** and give me a person.
>
> It works fine.

**Evaluate Statement (@DbLookup) in a Class**

I have a class DirectorSucursal.

```
Class DirectorSucursal

    Private m_branch As String

    'Constructor class
    Public Sub New (branch)
        Dim subString As String
        subString = Left(branch, 2)
        me.m_branch = subString
    End Sub

    'Deleter Class
    Public Sub Delete

    End Sub

    'Sub show the code about Suc
    Public Sub GetCodSuc
        MsgBox m_branch
    End Sub

    'Function get the name director
    Public Function getNameDirector As String
      Dim varResult As Variant
      varResult = Evaluate({@DbLookup("":"NoCache";"C1256EAD:00478951";"People2"; "D} & m_branch & {"; "FullName)"})
      getNameDirector = CStr( varResult(0) )
    End Function

End Class
```

Then, in a button I instantiate the new object DirectorSucursal with the parameter of the field doc.LlcPoliza(0) like this.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim director As New DirectorSucursal(doc.LlcPoliza(0))
    director.GetCodSuc
    director.getNameDirector
end Sub
```

> The field `doc.LlcPoliza(0)` has the value **C2H2H2**. `GetCodSuc` show the value **C2**, but the function `getNameDirector` doesn't work.
>
> It shows the error:
>   **Operation failed**

**Evaluate Statement (@DbLookup) in click button**

I have tried the same but into a click sub.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim subString As String
    subString = Left(doc.LlcPoliza(0), 2)

    Dim eval As String
    eval = Evaluate({@DbLookup("":"NoCache";"C1256EAD:00478951";"People2"; "D} & subString & {"; "FullName)"})

    Msgbox eval
End Sub
```

> The field `doc.LlcPoliza(0)` has the value **C2H2H2**. But it doesn't work
>
> It shows the error:
>   **Operation failed**

My question is: **what am i doing wrong? Why the code works fine in a calculate text with @Formula but with Lotusscript not?**

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

I have added and Error Goto, modified the class code, modified @dblookup in calculate text and I have this error:

> Error in EVALUATE macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) My suggestion is to never (or at least very seldom) use Evaluate() in Lotusscript. You have proper Lotusscript functionality to do almost everything.
One of the major reasons is that the code is very hard to debug (which is what you are now experiencing).

2) Don't use extended notation when you work with fields. The best practice is to use the GetItemValue and ReplaceItemValue methods of the NotesDocument class for performance reasons as well as compatibility reasons.

3) In the examples with buttons you have a reference to doc, but it is never declared or initialized in the code. If you would use Option Declare at the top of your code you would catch these kinds of errors.

4) I also reccomend against using replica ID to reference databases, that makes it very hard to maintain in the future. Unless you have a very good and convincing reason, reference them by server and filename instead.

I would suggest you refactor your code to something like this:

```
'Function get the name director
Public Function getNameDirector() As String
  Dim db as NotesDatabase
  Dim view as NotesView
  Dim doc as NotesDocument
  Dim key as String
  Dim fullname As String
  Dim varResult As Variant

  Set db = New NotesDatabase("Server/Domain","path/database.nsf")
  If db Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Unable to open 'path/database.nsf'"
      Exit Function
  End if
  Set view = db.GetView("People2")
  If view Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Unable to access the view 'People2'"
      Exit Function
  End if
  key = "D" & m_branch 
  Set doc = view.GetDocumentByKey(key)
  If doc Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Could not locate document '" & key & "'"
      Exit Function
  End if
  fullname = doc.GetItemValue("FullName")(0)
End Function
```

Ando of course update the button actions in the same way.

Yes, it is a few lines longer, but it is much more readable and easier to maintain and debug. And you have error handling as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advices Karl. And the refactor of the code is better than the original. I agree with you that it 's more readable and easier to maintain. I really apreciate your advices. Thanks. To the future i will try to use the notesdocuments class. I have to learn a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Please read documentation and use help! evaluate always returns an ARRAY, as stated in the help:

> **Return value**
>   ***variant***
>   The result of the evaluation. A scalar result is returned.

To make your code return a STRING you need to change it like this:

```
Public Function getNameDirector As String
    Dim varResult as Variant
    varResult = Evaluate({@DbLookup("":"NoCache";"C1256EAD:00478951";"People2"; "D} & m_branch & {"; "FullName")})
    getNameDirector = Cstr( varResult(0) )
End Function
```

The CStr is just there for the case where the @DBLookup returns an error or a number (both possible)

Just a few things in general:

- NEVER write even one line of LotusScript- code without error handler. It will cause you trouble FOR SURE. If you had error handling in place, then it would have told you in which line the error occured...
- NEVER use the result of @DBLookup without checking for @IsError... It will cause lot of troubles when the lookup fails.
- IF you use @Iserror, then don't do the Lookup twice, assign the lookup to a variable and check that one for @Iserror, like this. Otherwise performance will go down in big forms:

Example:

```
_lkp := @DbLookup("":"NoCache";"C1256EAD:00478951";"People2"; "D"+suc; "FullName");
@If( @IsError( _lkp ) ; " " ; _lkp )
```

EDIT: As Knut correctly stated in his answer the real cause for the error was a typo in the formula ( `Fullname)"` instead of `Fullname")` that I fixed in my example as well.

Comment: Thanks for yours advices, i will change the @formula codes. With the class, i have changed it but it still with the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Change your last part in @DbLoookup code line to:

```
 "FullName")})
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot Knut.